# How to fix a creaky carpeted floor?

Tags: floor, carpet, noise

I recently moved to a 30ish year old building.

The master bedroom's carpeted floor creaks horribly when anyone walks across it - loud enough to wake my wife and daughter in the next room at night!

Not all of it creaks.  Just a roughly 5ft x 10ft area.  Of course, that area is the path between the bed and the door.

What is the easiest way to eliminate or at least reduce the creaking?  Preferably without pulling out or damaging the carpet.

Answer (score 3):

They make special screws just for your problem. After you screw it down they break off, leaving the screwed portion below the level of the carpet pad. Do an internet search.

[image]